# How to use OWIN forms authentication without aspnet identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, forms-authentication, owin

I want to use the OWIN pipeline to emit the authentication cookie to the client, clear the cookie when the user signs out etc but I don`t want to use the annoying aspnet identity provider. It just doesn't fit on the project, I tried for a long time and it just doesn't fit. So I decide I won't use it. I just want to use the OWIN pipeline.

Is this possible or I should fall back to the old forms authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Brock"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "brockallen@gmail.com"));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Taken from [here](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/).

Comment: DefaultAuthenticationTypes is part of identity (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes)